# Error in dynamic link in linux in QtCreator C++

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I'm new in developing shared object, so don't have some knowledge of these.
I made simple shared object that use another (libmodbus).

Used next commands to compile my library:

```
g++ -fPIC -c -o modbus-rtu-server.o modbus-rtu-server.cpp -lmodbus -lpthread
g++ -shared -o ./libs/modbus-rtu-server.so modbus-rtu-server.o -lmodbus
```

So got library modbus-rtu-server.so

In qt application this lib opened via dlopen, so to get some functions i used dlsym. And all worked fine, until i wrote one line and recompile *.so file.

```
modbus_set_indication_timeout(ctx, 0, 1000);
```

After this qtcreator tell about undefined symbol on this function.

And this is happening only if I run application from qtcreator. If application run as normal (./app) than no problem occurred and library link successful and work fine.

I would like to know reason of this, for understanding is it dangerous in future.

Edit:
So, the problem was solved when libmodbus was compiled as static library and used in my shared library. Seems that main problem in compiling and linking shared object with another shared object (but i'm not sure in it)

Comment: It's not clear that you have a _linkage_ problem or _runtime_ problem.